# Use image as a Wordpress conditional

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a image as a conditional to show different post types. I have one post with images and another one without images. So I built a If else statement and a while loop that calls the post. At the end I have a page number code. But the loop is infinite, I'm not finding where to close it. Some one can help me?

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="texto-longo">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>


  <div class="row-2 w-row">
   <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'paged'          => $paged,
      'cat'            => '3',
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="_w-image container-novidades">
            <?php if( get_field('imagem_do_evento') ): ?>
      <div class="w-row">
        <div class="column w-col w-col-4"><img class="<?php the_field('imagem_do_evento');?>">
        </div>
        <div class="colomn-text-novidades w-col w-col-8">
          <h1 class="txt-blue"><?php the_title();?></h1>
          <h3 class="txt-blue"><?php the_field('imagem_do_evento');?></h3>
          <p><?php get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
          <p><?php the_field('imagem_do_evento');?></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

     <?php wp_reset_query(); else : ?>

     <p>Ainda não temos novidades :(</p>

   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
        <nav class="navegacao-paginas">
         <div class="paginacao twisted w-inline-block">
            <div class="seta-text"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link( '&#10230;' ); // display newer posts link ?></div>
          </div>
          <div class="paginacao w-inline-block">
            <div class="seta-text"><?php echo get_next_posts_link( '&#10230;', $wp_query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      <?php } ?>

  </div>
     <?php wp_reset_query(); else : ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the endwhile and edn if in the same row like this 
`<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it Out. It was a div opening outside the if statement. And I wasn't closing all if else properly. Check out the final code.

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="texto-longo">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>


<div class="row-2 w-row">
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'cat'            => '4',
        );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>


                <?php if( get_field('foto_novidades') ): ?>
                    <div class="_w-image container-novidades">
                    <div class="w-row">
                        <div class="column w-col w-col-4"><img class="img-novidades" src="<?php the_field('foto_novidades');?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="colomn-text-novidades w-col w-col-8">
                            <h1 class="txt-blue"><?php the_title();?></h1>
                            <h3 class="txt-blue"><?php the_field('sub_titulo_novidades');?></h3>
                            <p><?php get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
                            <p><?php the_field('texto_novidades');?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            <?php else:?>

                <div class="container-novidades">
                    <h1 class="txt-blue"><?php the_title();?></h1>
                    <h3 class="txt-blue"><?php the_field('sub_titulo_novidades');?></h3>
                    <p><?php get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
                    <p><?php the_field('texto_novidades');?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
        <nav class="navegacao-paginas">
            <div class="paginacao twisted w-inline-block">
                <div class="seta-text"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link( '&#10230;' ); // display newer posts link ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="paginacao w-inline-block">
                <div class="seta-text"><?php echo get_next_posts_link( '&#10230;', $wp_query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>


    <?php wp_reset_query(); else : ?>

    <p>Ainda não temos novidades :(</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```